# showing TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable in Odoo

Tags: python, odoo

I am getting this error when I am trying to change the license_id in odoo

```
    @api.multi
    @api.onchange('license_id')
    def del_potential(self):
        _logger.info('Status Approved or not' + str(self.license_id.approval_state))
        _logger.info('Potential FGL' + str(self.partner_potential_fgl_address))
        if self.license_id.approval_state == 'approved':
            so = self.env['sale.order'].browse(id)
            # _logger.info('del_potential id:'+str(so))
            so.partner_potential_fgl_address = False
```

Can anyone please guide why I am getting this error?

Sorry it is my bad it should be

```
so = self.env['sale.order'].browse([self.id])
```

instead of

```
so = self.env['sale.order'].browse(id)
```

Comment: @Paramitra, can you add your error in same question ?

Comment: Please give the FULL traceback of the error and line is occurred on.

Comment: I got it thanks for checking. I edit my post

Comment: @Paramita if you get your answer, please update in asnswer and select same as correct answer for this, that way you will close the workflow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this,

```
@api.multi
@api.onchange('license_id')
def del_potential(self):
    for rec in self:
        _logger.info('Status Approved or not' + str(rec.license_id.approval_state))
        _logger.info('Potential FGL' + str(rec.partner_potential_fgl_address))
        if rec.license_id.approval_state == 'approved':
            rec.partner_potential_fgl_address = False
```

This is not required as self contains list of browsable recordset, so you don't need explicitly browse any ids..

Don't use

```
so = self.env['sale.order'].browse([self.id])
```

Use instead

```
self.id or self.field_name
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that makes more sense